Store the stdout of NodeJS spawn as a string in a variable
I have a weird situation. I am building an Electron application, and need to return a function that will run an executable in the background and then return the output to the Renderer process. I have the IPC part working but can't seem to figure out how to return the stdout of spawn as a variable that I can use within my React code. Here is the script I am currently using:
import { spawn } from 'child_process'
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { dirname } from 'path'

const _dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

const exePath = path.resolve(_dirname, 'pict.exe')
const demoPath = path.resolve(_dirname, 'demo.txt')

const demo = () => {
  let output = '';

  try {
    const child = spawn(exePath, [demoPath]);

    child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
      output += chunk.toString();
    });

    child.on('exit', () => {
      console.log(output);
    });

    return output;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error
  }
}

const final = pict_demo();
console.log(final);

I know the spawn call is working because the console.log(output) is giving me the expected result. However, the "final" variable is empty and the console.log is outputting nothing. How can I properly store this result as a variable?
I have tried as many solutions on StackOverflow as I could, but many of the answers are quite outdated. I want to know the best way to do this now.

The output variable is only going to be up-to-date after the exit event occurs. Right now, the code returns output before the child has output anything. Standard async problem. Make demo an asynchronous function and await its return. See the duplicate for how.

the output variable is empty because you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. In the example you have shown:
This runs first
const child = spawn(exePath, [demoPath]);

Adds your functions to an array of event handlers. So that when that event fires your function can fire.
child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  output += chunk.toString();
});

child.on('exit', () => {
  console.log(output);
});

Returns the output:
return output;

So it returns the output even before any of the events are handled. (Can check even loop if you need more information)
To handle any asynchronous scenario you may need to wrap them in Promise. But, for current solution you can just use spawnSync.
An example:
const ls = cp.spawnSync('ls', ['-l'], { encoding : 'utf8' });
console.log('stdout here: \n' + ls.stdout);

Additional info:
Just giving an example how you would wrap this in promise.
const demo = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let output = '';
    try {
      const child = spawn(exePath, [demoPath]);

      child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
        output += chunk.toString();
      });

      child.on('exit', () => {
        console.log(output);
        res(output); //resolve here
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      rej(error); //reject here.
    }
  })
}

Then just can do:
demo().then(output => console.log(output)).catch(error => console.log(error));

or in a async function:
async runner() {
  try{
    const output = await demo();
    console.log(output)
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}

